# JavaScript: assign unique ID to elements containing a certain class

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

So I have this HTML code:

```
  <p style="margin-bottom: 5px"><span id="" class="stars-container stars-custom">★★★★★</span></p>
```

basically I want to assign a unique id to each instance of this element, so first element `id="1"`, second element `id="2"` etc.

I was thinking of using `getElementsByClassName` to identify them and grab the class name, but how do I assign and a unique id?? I'm pretty new to JS so I don't get how the loop will look like.

Comment: What's the point of using ids when they are dynamic? You can always uniquely identify each element by reference.

Comment: You could use `getElementsByClassName` and assign the resulting collection to a variable. Then iterate over the `length` of the collection, and for each item, assign it a unique ID (you could increment some variable each loop, or use the loop counter itself)

Comment: I'd start by doing a little research on [how to write a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle. You basically select all of the `p` elements with the classes you indicate, loop over them and set the id for each of them to the index of the loop variable.

I could not use a `foreach` loop as it's not usable on `HTMLCollections`

```
const paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('stars-container stars-custom');

for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) paragraphs[i].setAttribute('id', i + 1);
```

Comment: This certainly works for what I need thank you so much for your time!